# Trying to register multiple instances of object using static method and static hash object

Tags: javascript, factory-pattern

I don't know if I'm describing this properly, but I'm trying to use static members to handle storing and fetching object instances, but it is not working and doesn't throw an error in FireBug. When it gets to MyClass.instances[id] = new MyClass(cfg); execution just stops.

```
/*
I want to be  able to call like so:

MyClass.register('34', cfg);

and then use like...

MyClass.get('34').someMeth();

*/


/*  MyClass  */
var MyClass = function(config){
    this.init (config);
};

/* static var to hold instances    */
MyClass.instances = {};

/* static method to register an instance   */
MyClass.register = function (id, $cfg) {

    //this is where it goes poof.... no error just stops
    MyClass.instances[id] = new MyClass(cfg);
    return;
}

/* static method to get an instance   */
MyClass.get = function (id) {
    return MyClass.instances[id];
}



/* object instance methods here  */
MyClass.prototype = {

    init: function () {

    },

    someMeth: function () {

    },
}
```

Comment: For a starter on Factory pattern in JS consider this: http://2007-2010.lovemikeg.com/2009/06/26/the-factory-pattern-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass.prototype.init` isn't defined in your code. This means that `this.init` is undefined when you create a `new MyClass`. I don't know why such an error wouldn't show up in Firebug, however.

Comment: Sorry, I left it out. It is in there, I just didn't include all the methods for brevity sake

Comment: Doah! It was a typo. I had dollar sign in there: $cfg . That's what happens when you go back and forth from js to php

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're creating objects just to register somewhere with arbitrary keys.  Perhaps this will give you what you want

```
var register = [];

var obj = {
  i: 'gots',
  mad: 'properties'
};

var newObject = Object.create( obj );
newObject.i = 'don't gots';

register.push( newObject );

var anotherObject = Object.create( obj );
anotherObject.i = 'got mad';

register.push( anotherObject );

var whatObject = register[0];

console.log( whatObject.i ); //don't gots
console.log( register[1].i ); //gots mad
```

Comment: It has to do with having multiple instances of an object on the page and yet having only a single global var. It works, I just had a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was a typo. I had dollar sign in there: $cfg .  That's what happens when you go back and forth from js to php

```
MyClass.register = function (id, $cfg) {

//this is where it goes poof.... no error just stops
MyClass.instances[id] = new MyClass(cfg);
```